# Java install appears to be broken

Tags: windows-7, java

I installed JDK x64 for an application that required it to run. It turned out that that application needed x86, so I deleted x64 (it was not in Win7's list of installed software) and installed x86. Now when I go to launch the app I get

**The registry refers to a Nonexistent Java Development Kit installation or the runtime is corrupted. The system cannot find the path specified.**

Furthermore, java - version returns

```
java version "1.7.0_02"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_02-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 22.0-b10, mixed mode)
```

Yes, I checked Windows Path. Yes, it points to the right place.

Thanks much in advance for any help

Joe

Comment: Sounds like application is broken.  It should have worked if you install x64 SDK considering there literally is no difference, at least nothing a compiled application would know about, if it was actually tested.

Comment: Are you sure that the path is actually pointing to JDK? From your post I'd say it points to 64 bit JRE (assuming you managed to delete the 64bit JDK). Also did you try the most obvious solution: uninstall 32 and 64 bit JDK and JRE and then install 32 bit JRE, 64 bit JRE, 32 bit JDK and then 64 bit JDK? Also what's the application? I know I had to change settings manually in some applications that used 32bit JNI to point to the 32 bit version of java.

Comment: @Ramhound It would matter if the application is using JNI for example.

Comment: I went back to windows 7 installed programs and all of the jre x64 stuff was there unfortunately. I suppose I will have to reinstall x64 and uninstall it. I'll handle that tonight. Now I gotta run, but thanks again for the ultra-fast help. If anybody's on around 10 PM I'd appreciate some help in chat. Thanks again, Joe